# Why PHP returning wrong time from timestamp in CEST timezone?

Tags: php

I've strange issue. This is a sample code I have:

```
<?php
// 18000 / 3600 = 5
var_dump(
    gmdate('H:i', 18000), //requested time in UTC
    date('e'), //current timezone
    date('P'), //time offset in current timezone
    date('H:i', 18000) //requested time in current timezone
);
```

This is output:

```
E:\msf\www\test.php:3:string '05:00' (length=5)
E:\msf\www\test.php:3:string 'Europe/Prague' (length=13)
E:\msf\www\test.php:3:string '+02:00' (length=6)
E:\msf\www\test.php:3:string '06:00' (length=5)
```

How can be 5+2=6? Why is PHP date returning wrong time in specific timezone?

- PHP Version 7.1.24
- Build Date    Nov 8 2018 05:10:41
- Compiler  MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
- Architecture  x64

php.ini contains:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone="Europe/Prague"
```

Comment: You pass 18000 as timestamp. Which is: Date in your timezone*: 1/1/1970, 6:00:00 AM Standard Time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're applying the unix timestamp (`18000`) only to the first and the last function call. Which means the result of the second and third call is referencing the current date time (around 2020-09-09 as of we speaking).

Prague have a [daylight saving time practice](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague). From March to October, their time moves 1 hour forward. That means right now, Prague time is +02:00. But in January 1970 (timestamp `18000`), Prague time was +01:00.

To get coherent results, you need to apply the same timestamp to all your datetime-related function calls:

```php
$timestamp = 18000;

var_dump(
    gmdate('H:i', $timestamp), // requested time in UTC
    date('e', $timestamp), // timezone of the given timestamp
    date('P', $timestamp), // time offset in current timezone
    date('H:i', $timestamp) // requested time in current timezone
);
```

Result:

```
string(16) "05:00"
string(13) "Europe/Prague"
string(6) "+01:00"
string(16) "06:00
```

A piece of tips when thinking about time: always think about (and store) timezone with reference to location (e.g. `"Europe/Prague"`) instead of the hours-shifted (e.g. `"+01:00"`). Different place have different practice of shifting time. The practice also changes with time (e.g. some place would take up / abandon the DST practice at specific date in the history).

Comment: Now I understand. 18000 means 1970-01-01 05:00 UTC. Which is not in current part of year with different time offset because of daylight saving. I've to add 18000 to current midnight to get it right for current time offset.